# How can I remove a celery task from queue?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, celerybeat

There is an old celery task which is running periodically and sends a reminder email to some employees. Because of spam complains we have to remove this automatically reminders.
But simply deleting that part of python code for this task, doesn't end the functionality, more reminders are periodically sent. We use the UI from celery flower and there is no auto-reminder task running...
How can I remove the "phantom" task from celerybeat?
Why erasing the code for celery task didn't stop it running?

Comment: You probably need to remove it from your beat schedule backend -- usually, this is the database scheduler, but depends on your configuration. I'm not sure if schedules can be managed via `flower` or not. Also make sure you're actually updating all of your celery workers.

Comment: are you sure that this code was deployed to all workers? can you find the beat configuration file that define cron for this task? it's easier to delete this call instead of removing the task's code